# Why is there no Prolog compiler in the software center

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, software-center

How can I compile prolog codes in Ubuntu? I searched `Prolog` in the Ubuntu software center and it returns only `jEdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install *gprolog* package for the compiler.

The *Software Center* doesn't display things which aren't applications that won't show up in the main menu, generally. System packages are filtered out. If you search for *gprolog* in *Software Center* though, you should be able to install it.